# Webpack 2 HMR on Preact App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement, preact

I'm trying to setup Hot Module Reloading with Webpack **2** and Preact. It's "working", in that it's reloading the entire contents of the app every reload, but I'm getting errors between hot reloads (and I think that's why individual components aren't the only thing reloading).

**Here's the relevant parts of my webpack setup:**

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    //etc.
],
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?'+DEV_SERVER,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './dev/jsx/index.jsx'
],
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/'),
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

My index.jsx file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './AppProvider.jsx';

const renderApp = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
};

renderApp();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.accept('./AppProvider.jsx', renderApp);
}
```

When I make a change in any of the project files, the app contents reload and I get the following errors:
[image]

Have any of you gotten this before? I've been Googling all day and haven't found anything...

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering the old AppProvider module, which is null when HMR kicks in.  You'll need to move the require()/import for AppProvider.jsx into your HMR handler [as shown here](https://github.com/developit/preact-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.js#L6-L21).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const renderApp = () => {
  let App = require('./AppProvider.jsx');
  App = App.default || App;   // if you're using ES Modules
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
};

renderApp();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./AppProvider.jsx', renderApp);
}
```

Comment: Still seeing the exact same errors after this change. In fact I copied over the whole file (excepting the React/DOM imports instead of directly Preact) but still see the same reload+errors I was seeing before.

Comment: Update: I feel really silly for not mentioning this in the question, but I'm running **Webpack 2** (noticed linked project is on webpack 1).

Comment: Hmm - are you using React Hot Loader?

Comment: Yeah, the latest 3.0.0-beta.6.

Comment: AFAIK that doesn't work quite properly with `preact-compat`. It's something on my todo list (literally have the tabs open right now haha)